# How to respond to incoming messages to TCPListener Can I reuse existing connection?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, network-programming

I created TCP Server. It gets the message from a client and I would like send back response to it: `"test meesage"`. I suppose that I have to use `TCPClient` class this time but I am not sure and I do not know why. I already have a connection between them, maybe I can reuse it? I marked as comment place in code where I want to send message back.

**How send message back to the client?(marked as comment in the bottom of the code)**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace HomeSecurity {
    class TCPEventServer {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;
        public static readonly string SWITCH = "SWITCH";
        public TCPEventServer() {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13000);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }
        private void ListenForClients() {
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (true) {
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                 System.Media.SoundPlayer notificationPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("beep.wav");
                 notificationPlayer.Play();
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("przyszlo cos");
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
        private void HandleClientComm(object client) {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("przyszlo cos");
            while (true) {
                bytesRead = 0;
                try {
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("przyszlo cos");

                } catch {
                    break;
                }
                if (bytesRead == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                //wiadomość została pomyślnie odczytana
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                string messageDecoded = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
                messageDecoded = messageDecoded.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
                string ip = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address + "";
                Console.WriteLine("message: " + messageDecoded + " ip: " + ip);

                if (messageDecoded.Split(' ')[0].Equals(SWITCH)) {
                    //przeprowadzenie autoryzacji
                    string login = messageDecoded.Split(' ')[1];
                    string password = messageDecoded.Split(' ')[2];
                    if (authorized(login, password)) {
                        VideoStream.SECURED = !VideoStream.SECURED;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("System secured: " + VideoStream.SECURED);
                        sendResponse();
                        //I WOULD LIKE TO SEND MESSAGE BACK TO THE CLIENT HERE
                    }
                } else {
                    VideoStream.PassMessage(messageDecoded, ip);
                }
            }
            tcpClient.Close();
        }

        private void sendResponse() {

        }


        private bool authorized(string login, string password) {
            return true;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: @L.B First of all it is a rude comment. Secondly yes, part of this code is copied from a reference source as snippet then modified for my purposes. If you had a bad day go somewhere else.

Comment: This needs more help than we can provide. Needs a tutorial. Not specific and well-defined enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @usr ElGauchooo helped me in 10 lines, it seems to work but now I have to wait for the message at telephone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change clientStream to a member variable:

```
private NetworkStream _clientStream ;

private void HandleClientComm(object client) {
    TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
    _clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
   ...
}
```

Then, use the stream to write your data:

```
private void sendResponse() 
{
    var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!");
    _clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
}
```